# postgresql not reachable in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I use docker-compose to set up a web service connected to a postgresql database. When I run `docker-compose up -d`, both mydb and web services are created, but the database is not reachable from the web service. I cannot understand why.

```
services:
  web:
    image: etherpad/etherpad:1.8.10
    depends_on:
      mydb:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "6080:9001"
    environment:
      - DB_TYPE=postgres
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_HOST=mydb
      - DB_NAME=postgres
      - DB_USER=etherpad
      - DB_PASS=mydbpass
  mydb:
    image: postgres:13
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mydbpass
      - POSTGRES_USER=etherpad
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

Comment: I think `web` and `mydb` should be added in a same network: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: @Tryph As described in the _Networking in Compose_ document you link to, Compose provides a network named `default` for you.  You shouldn't usually need to manually specify Compose `networks:` at all.

Comment: @Edouard When you say "the database is not reachable", what's the actual output you get?  If you run `docker-compose up` without a `-d` option, do you see all of the database startup messages before the application tries to connect to it?

Comment: @DavidMaze : Yes, I see all the database startup messages, and they confirm the database is up, and accepting connections : ```mydb_1  | 2022-02-22 14:31:10.548 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections``` . Furthermore, the healthckeck condition ensures the database is ok before lauching the web service.

Comment: @DavidMaze : The error message I get is : ```[2022-02-22 14:33:31.582] [ERROR] server - Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.18.0.2:5432``` for ```web_1``` service.

Comment: on my macine, pasting your config in a `docker-compose.yml` file and running `docker-compose up` ends with a functionnal install, and the etherpad app is reachable via the `IPAddress` (obtained with `docker container inspect <container name>`) of the web_1 container on port 9001.

So your config is not the problem.

Comment: @Tryph Thanks for your answer. This is so strange. No Idea on what could be wrong. Is there a way to use the ```docker container inspect``` command to understand if something is unusual ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with :

```
systemctl stop nftables
systemctl start docker
systemctl disable nftables
reboot
systemctl start docker
```

see: http://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36151#issuecomment-968356070

Answer (score -1):

For 2 containers (=instance of service) to communicate you need a network between them.

[Indeed depends_on is not enough, it just adds constraints on start-up/build.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on)

```
services:
  web:
    image: etherpad/etherpad:1.8.10
    depends_on:
      mydb:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "6080:9001"
    environment:
      - DB_TYPE=postgres
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_HOST=mydb
      - DB_NAME=postgres
      - DB_USER=etherpad
      - DB_PASS=mydbpass
    networks:
      - backend
  mydb:
    image: postgres:13
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mydbpass
      - POSTGRES_USER=etherpad
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - backend
networks:
  backend:
```

Comment: Compose provides a network named `default` for you.  Adding manual `networks:` blocks shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: depends_on adds a constraint that mydb healthcheck is Ok. In this config, this means that the database is ready (```pg_isready``` command).